# Need help showing $\cos(x + y) / \sin(x - y) = -2$ if $\tan(\pi/4 - x) = 3 \tan(\pi/4 - y)$.

Tags: trigonometry

I've tried manipulating the given relations using basic trig identities (which is all I know) but I wasn't able to prove anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

As $$\dfrac{3+1}{3-1}=?$$

write $\tan=\dfrac{\sin}{\cos}$ and apply [Componendo and Dividendo](https://brilliant.org/wiki/componendo-and-dividendo/)

Comment: This hint is a little cryptic and I'm sorry but not very helpful. Of course I did try writing $\tan = \sin/\cos$ to get $\tan(\pi/4 - x) = (\cos x - \sin x) / (\cos x + \sin x)$. I'm not sure how to apply comp/div here.

Comment: @user264885, Can't u write as $\sin/\cos$ in both cases and then apply the formula suggested

Comment: Thank you, I have the proof now. I was hoping this problem wouldn't require some obscure proof technique, though, so I'll keep this post open for now hoping to see a proof using the more mainstream tools.

Comment: @user264885, Is https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-componendo-and-dividendo-rule obscure?

Answer (score 0):

$\tan(\pi/4 - x) = 3 \tan(\pi/4 - y)$

$\iff \frac{\sin(\pi/4 - x)}{\cos(\pi/4-x)}=\frac{3 \sin(\pi/4 - y)}{\cos(\pi/4-y)}$

$\iff \frac{\cos(x)-\sin(x)}{\cos(x)+\sin(x)}=\frac{3 \cos(y)- 3\sin(y)}{\cos(y)+\sin(y)}$

$\iff \cos(x)\cos(y)+\sin(y)\cos(x)-\sin(x)\cos(y)-\sin(x)\sin(y)= 3\cos(x) \cos(y)+3\sin(x)\cos(y)-3\sin(y)\cos(x)-3\sin(x)\sin(y)$

$\iff 2\cos(x) \cos(y) + 4 \sin(x) \cos(y) - 4 \sin(y) \cos(x) - 2 \sin(x) \sin(y) = 0$

$\iff 2 \cos(x + y) + 4 \sin(x -y) = 0$

$\iff \frac{\cos(x + y)}{\sin(x - y)} = -2$